# How to download a LIVE HLS m3u8 stream on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, http-live-streaming

HLS streams can be "live" or "VOD". Downloading a VOD HLS stream is easy.

However, I want to download (or record) say 5 minutes of a LIVE HLS stream. Is this possible?

If I do so, I am sure I have to make significant changes to the m3u8 file... One reason is live streams do not have a "duration", but the stream I download has to be streamed as VOD so it must have a duration. There might be various other changes required that I am not aware of. Presumably URLs of ts segments would also need to be changed.

Any tips or advice (hopefully actual code!)?

Thanks!

PS. Note that this question is not about playing back the stream in offline mode - I know I need an HTTP server for that.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. Do you have control over the server? There's a third type of HLS playlist - the Event type. It adds the segments to the playlist as they arrive, meaning you can seek back and forward at any time and after the final segment arrives it remains available as VOD.

Comment: @aergistal I have no control over the server. The streams are "live" m3u8 streams and I want to record them client-side. By client side I mean on an iOS app. "Recording" means downloading the m3u8 and all its ts segments. You are indeed correct that I could save it as a VOD OR EVENT playlist. Both are ok for me. But I want the code to download/record the stream and also change the playlist type and references to local URLs. Then I will allow playback through a local http server.

Answer (score 2):

The Live playlist uses a sliding-window. You need to periodically reload it after target-duration time and download only the new segments as they appear in the list (they will be removed at a later time).

Save the `#EXTINF` for each segment and start writing them in a VOD playlist using the same target-duration and a media sequence starting at 0.

When you want to stop recording add the `EXT-X-ENDLIST` tag at the end.

It doesn't matter how you name your segments as long as you use the same name in the `m3u8`.

Comment: This is helpful, but I have already done this & it works- but not always. It is a bit complex. U need to keep downloading segments (segs), but then u might find that some segments take longer time to download because of n/w latency. So you might lose some packets. the duration of each seg may not be accurate, so when u build your index m3u8 u need to re-check all the seg to get the correct duration.  Finally, u may need 2 try d/loading multiple times for the same seg (if it fails), and might end up losing other segs in that time (needs multi-threading). Any source code would be really helpful.

Comment: You need to use threads and a download queue. The segments are kept for twice the playlist duration so you have enough time. You can check the duration and write the playlist when the recording ends.

Comment: Yes, I had done that too. Still breaks. I think writing this code to work 100% of the time may be fairly complex, but I'm still upvoting. It appears that this problem has been faced by a few people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671705/record-http-live-streaming-video-to-file-while-watching?lq=1 Source code would be great to mark as answered.

Comment: @CarlosF That's not how it works. On stackoverflow the asker must post the relevant source code which causes issues. Adding it will improve your chances of getting a specific answer.

Comment: Well, I have the code in Ruby... not iOS and up voted your answer. In my question I have indicated that source code is ideal. I am well aware of the theoretical aspect of what to do. Essentially you are building a player that writes to disk instead of to the screen.

Comment: Also a live stream loops segment names. So you could end up with a 100000.ts and hit the same 100000.ts another time.